# How to use substring conditionally before and after two different symbols in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A with ID col. Here is sample data -

```
ID
NT-QR-1499-1(2015)
NT-XYZ-1503-1
NT-RET-546-1(2014)
```

I need to select everything after first '-' from left and before '(' from the right. However, some records do not have '(', in which case, the second condition would not apply.

Here is what I need -

```
QR-1499-1
XYZ-1503-1
RET-546-1
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend storing that part separately if it's important. Parsing is messy, and this doesn't even deal with all possible issues (e.g. no dashes either): `SELECT SUBSTRING(ID, 
        CHARINDEX('-', ID) + 1,
        CHARINDEX('(', ID+'(')-1-CHARINDEX('-', ID)) FROM ...;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get it done in a CASE statement, although I'd definitely take any advice from Aaron;

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (ID nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO #TestData (ID)
VALUES
('NT-QR-1499-1(2015)')
,('NT-XYZ-1503-1')
,('NT-RET-546-1(2014)')

SELECT 
ID
,CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('(',ID) = 0
        THEN RIGHT(ID, LEN(ID)-CHARINDEX('-',ID))
    ELSE LEFT(RIGHT(ID, LEN(ID)-CHARINDEX('-',ID)),CHARINDEX('(',RIGHT(ID, LEN(ID)-CHARINDEX('-',ID)))-1)
END Result
FROM #TestData
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT y.i, SUBSTRING(ID, x.i + 1, IIF(y.i = 0, LEN(ID), y.i - x.i - 1))
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('-', ID)) AS x(i)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('(', ID)) AS y(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your column is not actually a single data element, but multiple data elements that have been concatenated together. A bad idea for database design, which is causing the problem that you're having now.

This should give you what you need, but strongly consider separating the column into the required pieces.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(id, CHARINDEX('-', id) + 1, LEN(id) - CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(id)) - CHARINDEX('-', id))
FROM
    My_Table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @str varchar(64);
DECLARE @start int;
DECLARE @length int;
SELECT @str = 'NT-QR-1499-1(2015)';
/*SELECT @str = 'NT-XYZ-1503-1';*/

SELECT @start = CHARINDEX('-', @str) + 1;
SELECT @length = CHARINDEX('(', @str) - @start;
IF (@length > 0)
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, @start, @length)
ELSE
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, @start, LEN(@str))
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT CASE
       WHEN CHARINDEX('(',ID) > 0
       THEN 
       SUBSTRING(ID,CHARINDEX('-',ID)+1,(CHARINDEX('(',ID)-CHARINDEX('-',ID)-1))
       ELSE 
       SUBSTRING(ID,CHARINDEX('-',ID)+1)
     END AS New_Column_Name
FROM Table_Name

First it will check whether "(" present or not .
If present then it will fetch the data from next position of "-" to before the position of "(".
otherwise it will fetch the data from next position of "-" to till end.